How to change Marker cluster count design in vue.js
I am using vue3-google-maps
import { GoogleMap, CustomMarker, MarkerCluster } from 'vue3-google-map';

Added markercluster which is coming with number count but I want to change background color of cluster count marker and also want to give border.
 <MarkerCluster>
              <Marker v-for="(property, id) in properties.filter(row => !lowestPrice(row.units)?.featured)" :key="id" 
                    :options="{ position: property.coords }" /> 
 </MarkerCluster>

I tried passing option object in Marker cluster render
<MarkerCluster :options = "{renderer : customRenderer}"></MarkerCluster>

const customRenderer = {
        renderCluster(cluster) {
          // Custom rendering logic for clusters
          const clusterIcon = '/assets/icons/passport.png'; // Example icon path
          console.log("Print customer marker",cluster)
          cluster.getMarkers().forEach(marker => {
            marker.setIcon(clusterIcon);
          });
        },
        renderMarker(marker) {
          // Custom rendering logic for individual markers
          marker.setIcon('/assets/icons/passport.png'); // Example icon path
        },
        clear() {
          // Clear logic if needed
        }
      };

But still not working getting some renderer error

Could you please a provide a sample sandbox for us to check?
